# How to split a list in python like below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

1. `['4', '5', '6', '8', '5', '9', '6', '2', '6', '5']`

   ```
    How can I get it to look like this:
   ```
2. `[45,68,59,62,65]`

**How to combine two or more list elements like  ['4','5'] to [45]**

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is to pair the initial data, then convert to int, `zip` and slices are a good way dot that

```
values = ['4', '5', '6', '8', '5', '9', '6', '2', '6', '5']
result = [int(a + b) for a, b in zip(values[::2], values[1::2])]
print(result)  # [45, 68, 59, 62, 65]
```

---

- `values[::2]` : one over two `['4', '6', '5', '6', '6']`
- `values[1::2]` : over over two, starting at 2nd `['5', '8', '9', '2', '5']`

Comment: Or using indexes `[int("".join(values[i: i + 2])) for i in range(0, len(values), 2)]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I won't verify but `[int(values[i] + values[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(values), 2)]` maybe faster